# Yii2. Access to higher level folder

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Simple question. I use `Yii2` advanced template. In `apache` I have `DocumentRoot "{$path}/www/yii-application1/frontend/web"`. How can I access `/www/yii-application1/uploads` in order to show image to user?
Following `code` does not work:

```
<?php echo Html::img('../../uploads/ring.jpg') ?>
```

It works with `DocumentRoot "{$path}/www/yii-application1/"`. But in this case an `index` page of website looks like `domain.com/frontend/web`. But I need just `domain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

**Step : 1**

First create **.htaccess** file in here `yii-application1/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with backend first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^backend/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/image/(.*)$ backend/web/image/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend/web/(assets|css|image)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(assets|css|js|img|font)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)$ frontend/web/image/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|image|font)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

**Step : 2**

Now create a `components/Request.php` file in `common` directory and write below code in this file.

**Request.php** file

```
<?php

  namespace common\components;

  class Request extends \yii\web\Request 
  {
     public $web;
     public $adminUrl;

     public function getBaseUrl(){
        return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl()) . $this->adminUrl;
     }

     public function resolvePathInfo(){
        if($this->getUrl() === $this->adminUrl){
            return "";
        }else{
            return parent::resolvePathInfo();
        }
     }
  }
?>
```

**Step : 3**

Now Installing component. Write below code in `frontend/config/main.php` and `backend/config/main.php` files respectively.

```
//Frontend
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_frontendUser', // unique for frontend
        ]
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'PHPFRONTSESSID',
        'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<alias:>' => 'site/<alias>',
        ],
    ],
    'request'=>[
        'cookieValidationKey' => '[gfhjghsdjks44fdf4fgf4fgfg5645ggxcvvc]',
        'csrfParam' => '_frontendCSRF',
        'class' => 'common\components\Request',
        'web'=> '/frontend/web'
    ],
]

//Backend 
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_backendUser', // unique for backend
        ]
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'PHPBACKSESSID',
        'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
    'request'=>[
        'cookieValidationKey' => '[ruiqwybnddiogj786789hzcassdas9dasdjufi]',
        'csrfParam' => '_backendCSRF',
        'class' => 'common\components\Request',
        'web'=> '/backend/web',
        'adminUrl' => '/backend'
    ],
]
```

Your `domain.com/frontend/web` problem solved to follow the above `steps`.
and you can access the `index` page for `domain.com/frontend/web` using `domain.com`.

Now You can access you image using

```
<?php echo Html::img('uploads/ring.jpg') ?>
```

Also  you can access the `domain.com/frontend/web/image` using below code

```
<?= Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/image/xyz.png', ['class' => 'retina']); ?>
```

also you get webroot path using this `Yii::getAlias('@webroot')`

Comment: I tried it, but how do I access ProductController.php in frontend/controllers/? 
I tried http://domain.com/product/ and added 'product' => 'product/index' or 'product' => 'frontend/product/index' in frontend/config/main.php's URL Manager, but it didn't work.

Comment: Umm... I don't know how to explain it more deeply, but perhaps this one is more deep:
I have frontend/controllers/ProductController, how can I access it using your settings? I tried adding: 'product' => 'frontend/product/index' and 'product' => 'product/index' in the config, and access it with domain.com/product, but it gives me 404 error

Comment: you try this `domain.com/product/index`

Comment: In the end, I was able to access domain.com/product by generating a module named "product" using gii

Comment: @vishub thank you for your answer, I tried your code, it works for the url, now localhost/my_app/ redirect on ==> localhost/my_app/frontend/web, but when I use Html::img('uploads/ring.jpg') it does not work. Do I have to use the urlManager in the frontend/config/main.php ?

Comment: I have a second problem, all the url generated with Html::a(...) have /frontend/web/

Comment: Resolve [Access Root Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494061/yii2-how-to-access-a-folder-in-root-folder/46500260#46500260)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use alise inside config array on web.php file of config folder like

```
 'aliases' => [
    '@uploads' => '@app/web/upload',
],
```

and use it in any where you want like

```
 <?= Html::img("@uploads/image/xyz.png", ['class' => 'retina']); ?>
```