# Yii2 .htaccess prevent to access images in backend

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have .htaccess file in my yii2 root directory to hide frontend/web and I'm uploading images in yii2-app/uploads.
Issue is I can't access images in backend due to this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]` , if I delete this line then images are accessible but frontend/web appears in url, How I can solve this? How I can create a special rule for access images?

In grid view:

```
[
 'label' => 'Image', 
 'attribute' => 'banner', 
 'format' => 'raw',   
 'value' => function ($data) {
      return Html::img(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'../../../uploads/'.$data->banner, ['alt'=>$data->title,'width'=>'20','height'=>'30']); 
   }
],
```

.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

Directory structure:

```
yii2-app
   --backend
   --frontend
   --uploads
```

Comment: Refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426427/yii2-access-to-higher-level-folder/38428685#38428685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added this rule before `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]` and working for me.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(uploads)
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/$1 [L]
```

Comment: also in an advanced configuration, you can replace uploads by storage to make the storage directory to be found