# 404 Not Found in dependent textbox in select2 widget in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to autofill a textbox (Customername, CustomerAddress, customerMobileno) when a dropdownlist(customerid) is selected.The customer Id is selected successsfully but something is going wrong when the controller action is fetched. I'm getting 404 error.I would like to mention that I'm using prettyurl as told here -  [Yii2. Access to higher level folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426427/yii2-access-to-higher-level-folder).

In firebug I'm getting the following error-

```
GET http://localhost:8080/amitopticals/debug/default/toolbar?tag=57a4b1623a201

200 OK
        90ms    
create (line 545)
GET http://localhost:8080/amitopticals/orders/orders/....php?r=orders/customer/get-for-customer&custid=2

404 Not Found
        10ms    
jquery.js (line 9175)
ParamsHeadersResponseHTMLCookies

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Object not found!</title>
<link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />
<style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ 
    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    a:link { color: #0000CC; }
    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
    span {font-size: smaller;}
/*]]>*/--></style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Object not found!</h1>
<p>


    The requested URL was not found on this server.



    The link on the
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/amitopticals/orders/orders/create">referring
    page</a> seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/amitopticals/orders/orders/create">that page</a>
    about the error.



</p>
<p>
If you think this is a server error, please contact
the <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.

</p>

<h2>Error 404</h2>
<address>
  <a href="/">localhost</a><br />
  <span>Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12</span>
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of my select2 widget and related javascript -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'o_customerid')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Customer::find()->all(),'c_id','customerDetails'),
                    'language' => 'en',
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Customer Details', 'id' => 'custid'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
                    ]); 
                ?>
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$('#custid').change(function(){   
    var custid = $(this).val();

     $.get('index.php?r=orders/customer/get-for-customer',{ custid : custid }, function(data){
        alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#orders-o_customername').attr('value',data.c_name);
        $('#orders-o_customeraddress').attr('value',data.c_address);
        $('#orders-o_customermobno').attr('value',data.c_mobileno);
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Controller Action in CustomerController -

```
public function actionGetForCustomer($custid)
    {
        $customer = Customer::find()->where(['c_id'=>$custid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($customer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use pretty url your resulting url should be

```
://localhost:8080/amitopticals/orders/customer/get-for-customer?custid=2
```

instead of  the resulting in you message header

```
://localhost:8080/amitopticals/orders/orders/....php?r=orders/customer/get-for-customer&custid=2
```

SO for you $get instead of

```
 $.get('index.php?r=orders/customer/get-for-customer',{ custid : custid }, function(data){
    alert(data);
    ........
```

You should use

```
 $.get('customer/get-for-customer',{ custid : custid }, function(data){
    alert(data);
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, the controller action was in CustomerController. but 'customer/get-for-customer' did not work neither did '/customer/get-for-customer'. Then I moved the controller action to OrdersController and tried 'get-for-customer' and it worked. But how can I use that from other controller(In this case CustomerController)?

Comment: There are 2 controllers in the orders module - OrdersController and CustomerController.

Comment: In customerController you can use Url::to('[Orders/get-for-customer']);  using UrlHelpers  you must add  `use yii\helpers\Url;`

Comment: @Tanmay  ..This time it went well .. it took only one comment .. good job

Comment: Improving day by day. Thanks to you. :)