# Yii2 advanced project htaccess not work for me

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I installes Yii2 Advanced Themplate in my RaspberryPi.
I config my backend/config/main.php and frontend/config/main.php according to [Yii Official wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx/) and create .htaccess file in root of my project as told as article.
but when i go to address :

```
http://localhost/myproject
```

i see list of my files and htaccess file not working.

[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnOJx.png)

Comment: Please refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426427/yii2-access-to-higher-level-folder/38428685#38428685

Comment: show your .htaccess file code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been solved.
my apache configuration was has been change by another people and mod rewrite has been disabled.