# Yii2 How to access a folder in "root" folder?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have made a website with Yii2 advanced template and I want to access files in the upload folder located in the "root" folder.
I have :

```
backend/web/
frontend/web/
uploads/
```

I have followed the 1st answer of [Yii2. Access to higher level folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426427/yii2-access-to-higher-level-folder)

So my .htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with backend first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^backend/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/image/(.*)$ backend/web/image/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend/web/(assets|css|image)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(assets|css|js|img|font)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ frontend/web/img/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|img|font)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

My common/components/Request.php file is

```
<?php

  namespace common\components;

  class Request extends \yii\web\Request 
  {
     public $web;
     public $adminUrl;

     public function getBaseUrl(){
        return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl()) .$this->adminUrl;
     }

     public function resolvePathInfo(){
        if($this->getUrl() === $this->adminUrl){
            return "";
        }else{
            return parent::resolvePathInfo();
        }
     }
  }
?>
```

My fronted/config/main.php

```
..
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        'class' => 'common\components\Request',
        'web'=> '/frontend/web'
    ],
```

Now I can access to my site with localhost/myapp (without /frontend/web/)

Before I could see the image in my upload folder with

```
Html::img('../..'/uploads/my-image.png')
```

But it does not work anymore, neither with ../../uploads nore with uploads/

How can I access the uploads folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in `.htaccess` file.

Add *uploads* directory **RewriteCond** like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(uploads)/
```

show below `.htaccess` file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with backend first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^backend/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/image/(.*)$ backend/web/image/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend/web/(assets|css|image)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(assets|css|js|img|font)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ frontend/web/img/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|img|font)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(uploads)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In vhost configuration create an Alias (replace real path of public folder) and allow to access to it, such as:

```
Alias /uploads /var/www/html/public

<Directory /var/www/html/public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then you can make requests to /uploads folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't modify the vhost config as my server is managed by Plesk and I don't have an SSH access, is there another solution?